# Meaning of ～かといえばそうではない

Tags: grammar

Another question from me. Reading a text, I stumbled upon the following sentence:

> では、テレビがあれば、万事それで済むかといえば、そうではない。

As always, stay safe and have a good day.

Comment: What part do you not understand? How did you attempt to understand it?

Comment: What if you parse it as 「では、テレビがあれば、万事それで済むか？」といえば、そうではない。?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could **some hypothetical thing** be true ? .... mmmmm, not necessarily.

"Putting 2 more engineers on the task should get it done quicker" かといえば、そうではない。

It's a rhetorical construct, similar to what politicians and C-level executives often employ:

"Do I think that it's a good thing that 200 people lost their lives? Of course I don't!"

"Do I think it could have been worse had we not stopped the blah blah blah? Yes I do."